# Проблема со стандартной функцией рассылки сообщений Laravel 5.6

Tags: email, laravel5

Для сброса пароля на сайте использую стандартный класс `ForgotPasswordController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
}
```

который ссылается на функцию `sendResetLinkEmail`

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

trait SendsPasswordResetEmails
{
    public function showLinkRequestForm()
    {
        return view('auth.passwords.email');
    }

    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateEmail($request);

        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                    : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);
    }

    protected function sendResetLinkResponse($response)
    {
        return back()->with('status', trans($response));
    }

    protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return back()->withErrors(
            ['email' => trans($response)]
        );
    }

    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker();
    }
}
```

в `Illuminate/Foundation/Auth`. В них ничего не менялось.

В процессе сброса, но почту прилетает вот ЭТО:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`HTML` просто вывален в шаблон. Почему то весь текст письма обрамлен с тег `<code>`.
Такая же петрушка на стандартных рассылках типо "Поздравляем вы успешно оформили подписку", но думаю все это связано.

Из за чего это может происходить? Может кто сталкивался.

Дополнение. Во `views/vendor` нашел `layout` этого письма:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<table class="wrapper" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table class="content" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            {{ $header or '' }}
            <!-- Email Body -->
                <tr>
                    <td class="body" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <table class="inner-body" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <!-- Body content -->
                            <tr>
                                <td class="content-cell">
                                    {{       Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse($slot) }}
                                    {{ $subcopy or '' }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {{ $footer or '' }}
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема была в строке 
`{{ Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse($slot) }}`

Прошлый программист парсил уже распаршенную переменную `$slot`
Убираем эту конструкцию и вуаля! Все работает.